# Getting mac address owner

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address, mac-address

Using nmap i notice it not only gives you mac address out of ping scan but also displays who owns the mac address, how can i reproduce this feature / is there a database freely available of this list? I would like to scan a subnet for all IP (already got that done in C#), get their mac address (in progress but seems easy), and then match only those owned by a certain company to SSH into (to be able to separate the devices in which i want to SSH vs network devices that may run linux on which i don't want to SSH).

Comment: "and then match only those owned by a certain company" --- what does this exactly mean? And what "who owns the mac address" this means as well?

Comment: Mac addresses are registered to vendors, i want to get a mapping from mac address to vendor, ironically i found my own answer and am about to post it

Comment: https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf --- is this what you're looking for? (took 20 seconds to google for)

Answer (score 3):

In the end i found this http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt which seems to be an up to date version of the full database.

Comment: Hey, Ronan - this is a link-only answer, can you please post the content of that list as the answer? ( just kidding ;)